Canvas blurring Issue in React Component
I’m working on a component that displays a video with a blurred mirrored canvas behind it here is the reference link.
The canvas is supposed to match the video dimensions and be updated in real-time. However the blur effect doesn’t appear as expected.
Here is the full component code and css to it.
///VideoWithBlur.tsx

"use client";

import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

const VideoWithBlur = () => {
  const [sidePadding, setSidePadding] = useState(20); // Initial padding in percentage
  const videoWrapRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
      const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
      const documentHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
      const maxPadding = 20;
      const minPadding = 5;
      const scrollMax = documentHeight - windowHeight;
      const newPadding = Math.max(
        minPadding,
        maxPadding - (scrollPosition / scrollMax) * (maxPadding - minPadding)
      );
      setSidePadding(newPadding);
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const tItem = videoWrapRef.current;

    if (tItem) {
      const canvas = tItem.querySelector(".canvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
      const video = tItem.querySelector(".reel") as HTMLVideoElement;

      if (canvas && video) {
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        if (ctx) {
          const draw = () => {
            canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
            canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
            ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            requestAnimationFrame(draw);
          };
          video.addEventListener("play", () => {
            draw();
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={videoWrapRef} className="h-screen w-screen flex items-center justify-center relative overflow-hidden">
      <div
        className="video-container"
        style={{
          paddingLeft: `${sidePadding}%`,
          paddingRight: `${sidePadding}%`,
        }}
      >
        <div className="video-wrap">
          <canvas className="canvas"></canvas>
          <video
            ref={videoRef}
            className="reel"
            src="/Final.mp4"
            autoPlay
            muted
            loop
            playsInline
          >
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoWithBlur;

//globals.css
.canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: blur(150px); /* worked once until refresh */
}


.video-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  transition: padding 0.3s ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.video-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.reel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 20px;
}


Here what i have so far:
I set the canvas size to match the video dimensions in the useEffect hook using canvas.width = video.videoWidth and canvas.height = video.videoHeight.
I applied a CSS filter: blur(150px) to the canvas. I've manage to get this blur to work one time, however this solution doesn't help. After i refresh the page the blur disappears until i manually adjust blur and/or size of canvas in code.
I implemented dynamic padding adjustment based on the scroll position using a state variable and event listeners. I expected canvas the padding to decrease as the user scrolls down and canvas to update it size then show blur, but that didn't help.
Does anybody know about this?
